# How to pin an input label to the top of the field?

Tags: sass, label, vuetify.js

Is there a way to fix the label so that it does not go down into the field and effectively become a placeholder?

I want it to stay up like this even when the field is not in focus and when there's no entered input:

[image]

I don't want it to be down like this:

[image]

It seems that the official component [API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props) doesn't support this out of the box, and I'm having a hard time targeting it using scss and making it stick at the top. Is there a way of doing this using scss only? (I'd like to not have to wrap all Vuetify input components into custom ones just to override how labels behave).

I found [this](https://vuejscode.com/how-to-align-v-text-field-label-using-reverse-tag-in-vuetifyjs) and I tried doing something similar to what was done there, but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use  persistent-placeholder like  below example

```
        <v-text-field
          value=""
          label="Outlined"          
          outlined
          persistent-placeholder
         ></v-text-field>
```

https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/mdqPXOd?editors=101

Comment: Hm, I tried this out earlier but it didn't work for me. But now I realized I'm on Vuetify 2.4.0, so perhaps that's the problem, I'll see if I can bump it up, and that might solve it. I'll get back once I do that. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Alright, bumping up to 2.6.3 fixed it. Thanks.